# Corrupted jpeg images occur after recover from file

Tags: c, cs50, recover, jpeg2000

I am recently trying to solve a problem from cs50 pset4 recover. It is about recovering images jpeg from raw file. The problem is I can retrieve image but my images return corrupted. Other ways to say,i want to write 512 bytes to each jpeg but my resulting jpegs are only 1 bytes. please help me check my codes and optimize.

can retrieve images and view
but not correct contents and corrupted
expect 512 bytes each but only 1 byte

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_SIZE  512
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE bufferRead[MAX_SIZE];
    char name[8];

     // Check usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    FILE* img=NULL;

    int i=0;
    while(fread(bufferRead,512, 1, file))
    {    

        // Check first four bytes
        if (bufferRead[0] == 0xff && bufferRead[1] == 0xd8 && bufferRead[2] == 0xff && ((bufferRead[3]&0xf0) == 0xe0))
        {
            sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg",i);
            img=fopen(name,"w");
            
            if(img == NULL)
            {
               return 1;
            }
            
            fwrite(bufferRead,512,1, img);
            //close the file
            fclose(img);
            i++;
        }
    }
    // Close file
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: `fwrite` is located in if clause, which means it will only write the first block of jpeg image where the signature starts, but not the rest. You should move `fwrite` outside of if clause.

Comment: thanks for help but it leaves me segmentation error

Comment: You were probably trying to access a pointer which points to nothing. This is forbidden and it will give segmentation error. I posted a solution, please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

One image tells thousand words. Visualizing how jpeg images are stored in the memory will enormously help in my opinion.

[image]

In the memory card, jpeg files are all stored together back to back. Once you find a signature of a jpeg, then you keep writing the memory blocks into image files. But you have to be always checking if there is another jpeg signature is found. Then you should close the image, and create another one. I modified your code for the right logic, please check the comments on what they do.

```
while(fread(bufferRead,512, 1, file))
{

    // Check first four bytes
    if (bufferRead[0] == 0xff && bufferRead[1] == 0xd8 && bufferRead[2] == 0xff && ((bufferRead[3]&0xf0) == 0xe0))
    {

        // If there is already an image found, then close.
        if (i != 0)
        {
            fclose(img);
        }

        // create a new jpg file.
        sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg",i++);
        // open the new jpg file.
        img=fopen(name,"w");
    }

    if(img != NULL)
    {
        // Write the data to a new jpeg file.
        fwrite(bufferRead,512,1, img);
    }

}
// Close img.
fclose(img);
// Close file.
fclose(file);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, this helps me a lot. Now i got accepted by check 50.Thank you.